# PostgreSQL 42601 error POST

Tags: nodejs, postgresql, backend

Buen día trato de hacer una inserción en un backend muy sencillo con NodeJS y conexión a PostgreSQL, cuando hago una inserción  POST en Postman en JSON

```
 {
    "email": "aldairIgnacio@gmail.com",
    "name": "Aldair",
    "lastname": "Ignacio",
    "phone": "3325530152",
    "password": "1234567"

}
```

me arroja el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el código de mi clase user que hace referencia al POST es:

```
User.create = (user) => {
    
   const sql = `
   INSERT INTO
   users(
      email,
      name,
      phone,
      lastname,
      image,
      password,
      created_at,
      update_at,
   )
   VALUES($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8) RETURNING id
    `;
    return db.oneOrNone(sql, [
      user.email,
      user.name,
      user.lastname,
      user.phone,
      user.image,
      user.password,
      new Date(),
      new Date()
   ]);

 }
```

El del controlador es

```
async register(req, res, next) {
        try {
            const user = req.body;
            const data = await User.create(user);

            return res.status(201).json({
                success: true,
                message: 'El registro se realizó correctamente',
                data: data.id
            });

        } catch (error) {
            console.log(`Error ca: ${error}`);
            return res.status(501).json({
                success: false,
                message: 'El registro no se realizó ',
                error: error
            });
        }
    }
```

Y finalmente la estructura de la base de datos

```
CREATE TABLE users(
    id bigserial primary key,
    email varchar(255) not null unique,
    name varchar(255) not null,
    lastname varchar(120) not null,
    phone varchar(50) not null unique,
    image varchar(120) null,
    password varchar(255) not null,
    is_available boolean null,
    session_token varchar(220) null,
    created_at Timestamp (0) not null,
    update_at Timestamp (0) not null
);
```

Cuál podría ser el error? Leí que era por sintaxis de error, pero no encuentro el error, si me podrían ayudar lo agradeceré bastante, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Después de ver letra por letra me di cuenta que mi error estaba en la consulta:

```
const sql = `INSERT INTO users(email, name,
      lastname,
      phone,
      image,
      password,
      created_at,
      update_at
   )
```

había puesto un "," despues del update_at